# MySQL: Can't match the same values of 2 tables after csv import

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, import, matching

I've got the following problem:
I have two tables.
The first table is my mapping table between two other tables, lets call it 't_mapping'.
The second one is a table where import some data from a .csv. Lets call this one 't_import'.

The problem is, that i can't match the values with a left join between these two tables, even though the values are exactly the same.

Here is an example:

**t_mapping:**

```
id, category
203, 'Bürotechnik'
109, 'EDV Zubehör'
```

**t_import:**

```
id, category
1, 'Bürotechnik'
2, 'EDV Zubehör'
```

Both columns are 'UTF8_general_ci' encoded and are type 'varchar(255)'.

My select statement is as following:

```
select
t_import.category,
t_mapping.category
from t_import
left outer join t_mapping on (t_mapping.category = t_import.category)
```

Comment: Try with something like `LTRIM(RTRIM(mapping.category)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(t_import.category))`

Comment: "I can't map the ids, because they are different with the real values." . . . Please edit your question and show samples of the values.

Comment: I did edit it with the real values. The table has 124 columns, so it is just the bare necessities. I also tried RTRIM and LTRIM but it didn't work. There are whitespaces (but only in the middle of a value) and umlauts (maybe thats the problem?) as you can see.

Comment: Start by checking both comparing with constant: "select * from t_import where category = 'Bürotechnik'" and "select * from t_mapping where category = 'Bürotechnik'"

Comment: Yep! Your query says: "...outer join from T_MAPPING on (MAPPING...". But I guess should be a transcription error...

Comment: Show us `CREATE TABLE` statement  for both tables please?

Comment: I can find "Bürotechnik" in t_mapping but not in t_import, even though it's deffinately there. What can be the problem here? I converted the csv to UTF without BOM before importing. Do I have to consider something else?

Comment: And I changed the MAPPING to T_MAPPING. That really was just a transcription error. If I update a category of a row in t_import from the imported 'Bürotechnik' to 'Bürotechnik' then I can match it with t_mapping. How can I solve this?

Comment: The only thing i can think about right now is line endings. How do you import the CSV Files?
I guess the CSVs are edited/created under Windows but mysql runs under Linux.
So each line in the CSV ends with CR/LF, MySQL import with LineEnding LF, so the CR is left over.
Your 'Bürotechnik' is actually 'Bürotechnik{CR}'.
Maybe there are other non visible Characters involved.
Check the CSV file in an advanced text editor (e.g. Notepad++) and show all characters. I bet that shows something.